# Resend email confirmation after customer changed his email address

Tags: magento-1.8, email

Magento's default behavior is to send a confirmation email to new customers, but if a customer that already has an account change his/her email address, Magento does not verify the new one. Is it possible to resend the confirmation email?

Answer (score 2):

Sure it is.

```
$customer->setConfirmation($customer->getRandomConfirmationKey());
$customer->sendNewAccountEmail('confirmation')
```

The "problem" is, then the customer can not longer log in.